# Logistical regression - very few 1's in response vector "Y"

Tags: regression, logistic

I am trying to develop a model for prediction of retention. The problem is that the retention is very rare - aprox. 0.2 %. So far I have been using logistical regression. Without much success however. For example, in the interval of predicted probability above 70 % I am getting 4 true retention clients and 157 wrongly predicted retentions.

I have spent quite a lot of time deciding what covariates to choose and what transformation to apply. I don't think I can improve that.

The question could be formulated also as the following. **How to use (or what to use instead of) logistical regression when the response vector "Y" contains very few 1's (0.2 % in my case)?**

If you think you should know what data I have, tell me and I will provide you with this information. But I don't think it's important. Anyway, I have enough data. About 1.5 mil rows, so about 3000 of 1's.

Comment: (1) usually use the term "logistic regression" (2) what are your events per variable. if >>10 then you likely have enough data. if EPV <20 could consider regularization  (3) logistic regression will provide best model unless there are significant interactions or non-linear effects your not modeling. (4) prediction is hard. what makes you think your model isn't good

Answer (score 1):

You have a quite high lift in the scored data. So your predictions are not necessarily "bad". What are classification statistics (e.q AUC) in the test data set?

Comment: (+1) Though a 2.5% observed retention vs over 70% predicted retention suggests some miscalibration.

Comment: I guess you are right. I will have to put more effort into the model.